# How to make an image appear when you mouse hover over a link

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, mouseover

I have been searching the internet on a way to make an image appear when I mouse over a link. I found one way that works but it does not work in chrome.

```css
ul#nav li a.orange {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-right: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 background-color: #f47521;
 border: solid;
 border-width:thin;
}

 a.orange img { display:none; }
 a.orange:hover img.showspanel { 
  display:block; 
 position:absolute;
 margin-left:350px;
   }

#orange{
 background-color: #f47521;
 color: #000;
 border-radius:4px;
 width:975px;
 height:36px;
 padding-left:25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<ul id="nav">
  <li> <a  class="orange" href="#"><strong>Shows<img class="showspanel" src="../images/shows.png"  alt="shows" /></strong>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o9b5j5op/

Comment: Yeah not seeing a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works however there always ways to go for crossbrowser compatibility.

```html
<div id="nav">
 <ul id="nav">
  <li> 
     <a onmouseout="hideImg(imageOne)" onmouseover="showImg(imageOne)" class="orange" href="#">
     <strong>
      Shows
      <img style="display:none;" id="imageOne" class="showspanel" src="../images/shows.png"  alt="shows" />
   </strong>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
<script>

function showImg(image) {
    var img = document.getElementByI(image);
    img.style.display = "block";
}
function hideImg(image) {
    var img = document.getElementByI(image);
    img.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

That should run in chrome firefox and IE